# Problem making Pascal's Triangle in C using Array

Tags: c, windows

i need to make a program that output Pascal's Triangle with user defined row in C using Arrays. so i made a quick code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r,  i, j, loop, res, sv = 0;
    static int par[0], rar[0];
    printf("Pascal Dy'eepost\n-----------------\nHow many thing do you want? ");
    scanf("%d", &r); par[r], rar[r];
    
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        par[i] = 0;
        rar[i] = 0;
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            if(j == 0 || i == 0) rar[j] = 1;
            else if (j == i) rar[j] = 1;
            else rar[j] = par[j] + par[j - 1];
                
            printf("%d ", par[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        
        for(int k = 0; k < r; k++){
            par[k] = rar[k]; //to sync the result with main array
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

it does run, but when i input 4 to make a 4 rows of Pascal's Triangle, its outputs

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 2 3 1
```

i dont know where i messed up, can somebody help me?

Comment: You declared your arrays to be zero-length.  You know that's a severe bug, right?  Any access to them invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, the `par[r], rar[r];` at the end of the `scanf` line does nothing.  It's dead code.

Comment: @TomKarzes i wanted to change array size depends on how much variable `r` so i declared my arrays to be zero-length just for place holder, and then change the array size with `par[r]; rar[r];`. and yeah `par[r], rar[r];` was a typo

Comment: You *wanted* it to work that way, but it doesn't.  Arrays don't change size.  Those arrays have size 0 for the life of the function. Why did you think there was some connection between `r` and the arrays?  Even if `r` had been used to declare their size, its value at the time of the declaration is the only value that's used.  You should read up on dynamically-sized arrays.  The code will never work as it is.

Comment: @TomKarzes i feel so stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code is so illegal it refuses to works as I want. Thanks to *Tom Karzes*. In the comments, he pointed out that I have some typos and I cant declare zero length arrays. So I fixed my code:

```
/*
    nama:   Aqil Gama Rahmansyah
    nim:    215060307111019

*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r,  i, j, k, sp;
    printf("Pascal Dy'eepost\n-----------------\nHow many thing do you want? ");
    scanf("%d", &r); int par[r], rar[r]; sp = r;
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < sp; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            if(j == 0 || i == 0) rar[j] = 1;
            else if (j == i) rar[j] = 1;
            else rar[j] = par[j] + par[j - 1];
                
            printf("%5d ", rar[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        sp --;
        
        for(int k = 0; k < r; k++){
            par[k] = rar[k];
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And it's finally working as I wanted.